# Pyaudio sound quality when playing a file

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

So I'm trying to run the following script on my raspberry pi:

```
"""PyAudio Example: Play a wave file."""

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

# read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# play stream (3)
while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

I created a WAV file using: `arecord -D plughw:1 --duration=5 -f cd -vv ~/rectest.wav`

When I play it like: `aplay ~/rectest.wav` it plays nicely and the sound is loud and clear.

When I use the script (run python play.py ~/rectest.wav) the sound quality is terrible. I've also noticed that the recording is 5 seconds but when I play it using the script it takes around 8-9 seconds for it to finish playing (it seems the distortion makes it longer).

What's going on here? How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a bigger `CHUNK` size? If the file is small enough, try reading the whole thing into memory and see if the works. It could be that your script simply isn't feeding the player fast enough.

Comment: Yes I have. 
Do you know where I could get a clear understanding of what each of those arguments mean? Chunk, channels, framerate etc? I feel like I'm guessing randomly

Comment: So I take it none of those things helped. Since PyAudio is just a Python layer over [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com), the latter's [documentation](http://www.portaudio.com/docs.html) might be helpful. There's also an article specifically on [Audio Latency](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/latency.html) -- which might be the problem -- and how to mitigate it on some platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the problem, but I get rid from it simply by just Mute the Gain control and decrease the volume of speaker and MIC till white level.

[image]

After that my sound quality become crystal clear mean more better.

so just open sound controller by this command

```
alsamixer
```

and then use your arrow keys to switch b/w options, volume `increase/decrease` of `Speaker/MIC` and use `SPACEBAR` to `mute/unmute` the `Control Gain`.